# How to delete plist file

Tags: xcode

I know how to create plist file but I need to delete plist file.
But I don't know how to do this.

```
    - (NSString *) save
{
    NSArray *path =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:myPath error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use file io method and then delete the file! search file io in programming language your working